# Is it possible to block a breath weapon with a shield?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons, shield

Most of us may have seen similar imagery:

[image: Dragonslayer]

How could a player character do as such, with a shield?

Anything RAW, and without resorting to spellcasting (if at all possible), would be nice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## In core folks do this with their [tower shields](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/armor.htm#shieldTower)

A creature fighting a dragon can take the [ready](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialInitiativeActions.htm#ready) action specifying the action as *I gain [total cover](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm#cover) from my [tower shield](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/armor.htm#shieldTower)* and the condition as *When the [dragon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dragonTrue.htm#redDragon) is about to use his [breath weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#breathWeapon)*. When the condition's met and the dragon uses its breath weapon anyway, most dragons' breath weapons no longer have [line of effect](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#lineofEffect) to the warrior because the warrior has sought refuge behind a barrier.

Although realistically (or as realistically as this situation gets, anyway) the tower shield ([hardness 5, 20 hp](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm)) should at least be *damaged* by many a dragon's breath weapon, because most dragons' breath weapons don't say they damage barriers (cf. *lightning bolt*), the tower shield remains unscathed afterward.

So while [tower shields have a poor reputation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48494/why-is-holding-a-tower-shield-a-bad-idea), this is one of the handful of ways they don't suck.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if it's designed in some way to resist such an attack. If it's a line effect breath weapon, like with a blue dragon's lightning, or something to that effect, then there's no reason a large shield wouldn't at least help against said damage. But a mundane shield would take damage and not necessarily negate anything that goes outside the shield's dimensions - ie the guy next to you would still be in the area of effect, if it's a cone and not a line. If your DM's version of the dragon only does a line breath, then sure, why not. But I'd say anyone right next to you would, all things being equal, take half the effect's damage in splash, because a shield used in this way does, in art, make the breath weapon go off to the sides instead. Deflection, in other words. Like how a surface would deflect a projectile. If it makes sense for a shield to deflect an arrow, then it would make sense - as much as a mundane shield protecting vs a line breath would - to parallel this if done correctly (hence readied action and breath condition).