# Does the tower shield's table entry trump the text?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, shield

The *Player's Handbook* on Armor on Maximum Dex Bonus on [Shields](http://dndsrd.net/armor.html#maximum-dex-bonus) says, "Shields do not affect a character’s maximum Dexterity bonus" (122), yet Table 7–6: [Armor and Shields](http://dndsrd.net/armor.html#table-armor-and-shields) in its entry for the tower shield gives the [tower shield](http://dndsrd.net/armor.html#tower-shield) a maximum Dexterity bonus of +2 (123).

This detail is untouched by the *Player's Handbook* errata, that, by the way, says "One example of [how rules conflicts are resolved between] a [primary/secondary source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56771/8610) is [having] text taking precedence over a table entry" (1). Further, while using a tower shield is covered by the [occasionally suspect](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/8610) *D&D Main FAQ*, that document likewise fails address this detail.

Must [a creature foolish enough to employ a tower shield](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48494/8610) also—technically—contend with its tower shield's maximum Dexterity bonus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The [*Player's Handbook*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786962461) (2012) updates this rule

The premium edition *Player's Handbook* (2012) includes stealth errata that changes the previous printing's sentence from, "Shields do not affect a character’s maximum Dexterity bonus," to—and I'm really not kidding here—the following: "Shields other than tower shields do not affect a character’s maximum Dexterity bonus" (123).

As it's the latest printing of the *Player's Handbook*, the premium edition takes precedence over previous printings, making it so that, yes, a tower shield—uniquely among the *Player's Handbook*'s shields—has a Maximum Dex Bonus. (It's +2.) Thus the poor blighter using a tower shield must, in fact, contend with this.

### "How does this change affect other shields?"

So far as this reader can tell, most of the game's other shields—including the exotic shields from *Races of Stone*—don't have a Maximum Dex Bonus, but the **chitin tower shield** (*Races of the Dragon* 121-2) (360 gp; 45 lbs.) and the **steel tower shield** (*Races of Stone* 158) (75 gp; 100 lbs.) do. (They're, respectively, +3 and +2.) However, as items named *tower shields* therefore presumably covered by the feat [Tower Shield Proficiency](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#tower-shield-proficiency) (*PH* 101), these shields will also likely be equally impacted by the stealth errata from the premium edition *Player's Handbook* in all but the most [rules-as-written](/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) of campaigns, forcing their users in most cases to also contend with those shields' Maximum Dex Bonuses.

The *real* outlying shield is the **hide shield** (*Sandstorm* 99) (50 gp; 30 lbs.) that's presumably covered by the feat [Shield Proficiency](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#shield-proficiency) (*PH* 100)—the text not noting otherwise, instead noting only that it can grant "cover as a tower shield does" and that it's "made of lighter material than a tower shield." *Sandstorm*'s Table 4–2: Wasteland Armor says that the hide shield has a Maximum Dex Bonus entry of +4.

As the hide shield is *not* a tower shield—neither in name nor (apparently) by proficiency—, and there's no explicit exception to core rules made by *Sandstorm* for the hide shield, and there's no *Sandstorm* errata, the Maximum Dex Bonus for the hide shield could be construed as *technically* an error, the primary source (the *Player's Handbook*) superseding the secondary (*Sandstorm*), eliminating the hide shield's Maximum Dex Bonus. However, a case can also be made for *Sandstorm* itself as the primary source for the hide shield therefore that book's table overriding even the *Player's Handbook* text.

This reader suspects that a player trying to convince a DM to allow the player's Dex 30 rogue to realize her full Dexterity bonus to AC while she uses a hide shield will see the DM rule in favor of *Sandstorm* as the hide shield's primary source… but it couldn't hurt to ask.